# How to get tweet updates in XML format using java

Tags: java, xml, twitter

I have following code that outputs my and my users twitter time line messages in java.
I followed this tutorial to get the code below

http://namingexception.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/how-easy-to-make-your-own-twitter-client-using-java/

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

public class SimpleTweet {

List<Status> statuses;
private final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXXX";
private final static String CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET = "XXXXXXX-123";

public void start() throws TwitterException, IOException {

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET);


String accessToken = getSavedAccessToken();
String accessTokenSecret = getSavedAccessTokenSecret();
AccessToken oathAccessToken = new AccessToken(accessToken,accessTokenSecret);

twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(oathAccessToken);

twitter.updateStatus("Hello world :).");    

statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
for (Status each : statuses) {

    System.out.println("Sent by: @" + each.getUser().getScreenName()
        + " - " + each.getUser().getName() + "\n" + each.getText()
        + "\n");
}

  }// start method ends here


private String getSavedAccessTokenSecret() {

return "vxcvvxcvxcvx";
}

private String getSavedAccessToken() {

return "eweweqweqweqwe";
}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
new SimpleTweet().start();
  }  
 }
```

And I get following output

```
Sent by: @tweetrr - rr
Hello to all :).

Sent by: @addthis - AddThis
Just in time for @wordcampnyc, we have updated the AddThis WordPress plugin! Check it:    
http://t.co/cgOgRwyl
```

Now I want the output to be in XML format. I would like to know if there are API's that does this work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you're after, but you can get XML timeline of one user with one simple GET request: https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.xml - no oauth, no authorisation - just one GET.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `betwixt` from `apache` ([Bitwix example](http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/guide/examples.html)), using which you can convert either bean or hashmap to XML format easily. So, you create bean called `UserStatusBean` with fields like `sentBy`, `status`, `message` etc, populate the bean and output as XML using `[BeanWriter][2]`.